# Connection issue while connecting to DB2 instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

I'm trying to connect to DB2 instance from my local MacOS. I tried with 2 python modules, but I'm getting the below errors for both modules. Any idea/suggestions how I can resolve this.

Tried many things after searching in google and checking in ChatGPT, but no success. Any light here will be much appreciated.

Python Version : 3.7.6

**Using pyodbc module**

```
    import pyodbc
    print(pyodbc.drivers())
    db2_params = {
        "DATABASE": "xxxxxx",
        "HOSTNAME": "xxxxxxx",
        "PORT": "449",
        "PROTOCOL": "TCPIP",
        "UID": "xxxxxxxx",
        "PWD": "xxxxxxxxx",
    }
    
    # Construct the connection string for IBM Db2
    conn_str = (
        f"DRIVER=IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER;"
        f"DATABASE={db2_params['DATABASE']};"
        f"HOSTNAME={db2_params['HOSTNAME']};"
        f"PORT={db2_params['PORT']};"
        f"PROTOCOL={db2_params['PROTOCOL']};"
        f"UID={db2_params['UID']};"
        f"PWD={db2_params['PWD']};"
    )
    
    conn = None  # Initialize the connection variable
    
    try:
        # Establish a connection to IBM Db2
        conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
        print('Connected Successfully to IBM Db2')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')
    finally:
        # Close the connection in a finally block to ensure it's always closed
        if conn is not None:
            conn.close()
```

**Error**

```
    ['ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server']
    Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

I tried to install the river, but there is no direct way or i haven't found any to do so.

**Using ibm_db**

```
    import ibm_db
    db2_params = {
        "DATABASE": "xxxxxx",
        "HOSTNAME": "xxxxxx",
        "PORT": "449",
        "PROTOCOL": "TCPIP",
        "UID": "xxxxxxx",
        "PWD": "xxxxxxx",
    }
    
    # Construct the connection string for IBM Db2
    conn_str = (
        f"DATABASE={db2_params['DATABASE']};"
        f"HOSTNAME={db2_params['HOSTNAME']};"
        f"PORT={db2_params['PORT']};"
        f"PROTOCOL={db2_params['PROTOCOL']};"
        f"UID={db2_params['UID']};"
        f"PWD={db2_params['PWD']};"
    )
    
    try:
        # Establish a connection to IBM Db2
        conn = ibm_db.connect(conn_str, "", "")
        print('Connected Successfully to IBM Db2')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Error: {e}')
    
    ibm_db.close(conn)
```

**Error**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/x/PycharmProjects/dev_test/cnc_ibm.py", line 1, in <module>
        import ibm_db
    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/x/PycharmProjects/dev_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ibm_db.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: ___cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length
      Referenced from: <855AE640-1BCF-3A61-A65E-58F5490BFF43> /Users/x/PycharmProjects/dev_test/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/clidriver/lib/libdb2.dylib
      Expected in:     <3F5CB4D5-26D1-3E43-B241-2688FF0A67BD> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
```

Answer (score 0):

For pyodbc, clidriver (or equivalent cli driver from IBM) has to be pre-installed and correctly configured.

For `ibm_db`, this is a KNOWN and DOCUMENTED symptom for which there are **workarounds**, see the README on the [support website](https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb) , in particular in the section "For MacOS M1/M2/ Apple Silicon chip system".

If you still have problems , after implementing the pre-requisites, then search on the ISSUES page for already closed tickets `is:closed`  that mention your symptom.

Comment: Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "10.x.xx.xxx".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-30081

Comment: was getting above error, any idea what exactly it is about?

Comment: @Sandeep several possibilities , including incorrect port number, or local firewall is blocking the port, or the db2 server is not listening on that port. Do not ask a new question in a comment. Instead create a new question